JQ filter and recompilation data
My data provider sends me data in 2 different structures.
Difference in imageValue field

object in about group
array in banner group

{
    "valuesToUpload": [
      {
        "groupId": "about_2",
        "groupTitle": "",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldType": "image",
            "valueId": "cd262467-e683-4b1a-8fff-b22c42722f2c",
            "toUpload": true,
            "imageValue": {
              "imageId": 27606887612,
              "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
              "url": "http://img10/image/1/1.YaE0cFYle0oRLlTPlS7HAwtEINoMkYFRuB_k"
            }
          },
          {
            "fieldType": "image",
            "fieldName": "example_images",
            "valueId": "5b394732-28c1-424c-a5c8-5edd553a3711",
            "toUpload": true,
            "imageValue": {
              "imageId": 27606306642,
              "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
              "url": "http://img40/image/1/1.j_RTsLassXjnkzZKMn-0czdeML_SxCdo-c"
            }
          },
          {
            "fieldType": "image",
            "fieldName": "example_images",
            "valueId": "efaeca0d-9dbe-4b1c-93a1-51cb54b9ec1b",
            "toUpload": true,
            "imageValue": {
              "imageId": 27606343705,
              "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
              "url": "http://img00/image/1/1.xNLAhbas-l50pn65eZTqgqHrazl2.r39lMZMqeTovl4Cj2EY"
            }
          }]
      },
      {
            "groupId": "banner",
            "groupTitle": "banner",
            "fields": [
              {
                "fieldType": "image",
                "imageValue": [
                  {
                    "imageId": 0000001,
                    "toUpload": true,
                    "valueId": "efaeca0d-9dbe-4b1c-93a1-51cb54b9ec00",
                    "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
                    "url": "https://20.img.st/image/1/link1"
                  },
                  {
                    "imageId": 0000002,
                    "toUpload": false,
                    "valueId": "efaeca0d-9dbe-4b1c-93a1-51cb54b9ec01",
                    "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
                    "url": "https://20.img.st/image/1/link2"
                  }
                ],
                "fieldName": "banner",
                "fieldTitle": "banner"
              }
            ]
       }
    ],
    "reload": {
      "on": false
    }
}


I need to "recompile" banner group image fields to format same as in about_2 group

I found out how to select only separate object format (about_2):


{"valuesToUpload":[
        .payload.valuesToUpload[]|{groupId,groupTitle,fields:[.fields[]| select(.valueId != null)]}
]}


And get only "about_2" section.
But how to write jQuery to recompile banner section to same format and not lost about_2 section.
Banner section must be like:
{
        "groupId": "banner",
        "groupTitle": "banner",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldType": "image",
            "valueId": "efaeca0d-9dbe-4b1c-93a1-51cb54b9ec00",
            "toUpload": true,
            "imageValue": {
              "imageId": 0000001,
              "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
              "url": "https://20.img.st/image/1/link1"
            }
          },
          {
            "fieldType": "image",
            "valueId": "efaeca0d-9dbe-4b1c-93a1-51cb54b9ec01",
            "toUpload": true,
            "imageValue": {
              "imageId": 0000002,
              "imageSchema": "profile_composition",
              "url": "https://20.img.st/image/1/link2"
            }
          }
        ]
}



Mind you, jquery, the JavaScript library, is not jq, the command-line JSON processor.

Use |= to partially update by traversing down on the LHS, selecting the parts being relevant (e.g. matching .groupId == "banner"):
(.valuesToUpload[] | select(.groupId == "banner").fields) |= map(. + (
  .imageValue[] | {valueId, toUpload, imageValue: {imageId, imageSchema, url}}
))

Demo


groupid or title can be random. I need to desire base on empty valueId or type of imageValue

As you've provided a solution using .imageValue | type == "array" yourself, here's my approach from above checking for a non-truthy .valueId:
.valuesToUpload[].fields |= map(select(.valueId) // . + (
  .imageValue[] | {valueId, toUpload, imageValue: {imageId, imageSchema, url}}
))

Demo

groupid or title can be random. I need to desire base on empty valueId or type of imageValue

@Oleg Updated to the modified input JSON, and added a variant checking for a non-truthy .valueId.

so I found solution that recompile only(!) fields with array in imageValue:
{"valuesToUpload":[.payload.valuesToUpload[]|
    {groupId,groupTitle,fields:
    [
    .fields[]|
    if .imageValue|type == "array"
        then .imageValue[] + {fieldName} +{checksIds} + {fieldTitle} + {fieldType} |                                                                   {
                                            checksIds,
                                            fieldName,
                                            fieldTitle,
                                            fieldType,
                                            toUpload,
                                            valueId,
                                            imageValue:{
                                                url,
                                                imageId,
                                                imageSchema
                                            }
                    }
        else .
        end 
    ]
}
]}

